# Урезается фон при отдалении

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Когда отдаляю экран (проверить как на большом экране будет смотреться) картинка урезается. Я ее задал фоном div'a и дал ей высоту, без высоты она пропадает. Или просто закинуть ее img?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Код CSS:**

```
.head {
margin-top: 20px;
width: 100%;
height: 530px;
background: url(img/head.jpg)no-repeat ;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что `background-size: cover;` заполняет блок, используя размеры `viewport`, а не размеры блока, в котором находится. Замените `background-size: cover;` на `background-size: contain`:

```css
.head {
  background: url("https://mobidevices.ru/images/2017/01/Nintendo-Switch-1.jpg") no-repeat 50% / contain;
  margin-top: 20px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 530px;
}
```

```html
<div class="head"></div>
```

Или же сделайте высоту блока равной всей высоты `viewport`:

```css
.head {
  background: url("https://mobidevices.ru/images/2017/01/Nintendo-Switch-1.jpg") no-repeat 50% / cover;
  margin-top: 20px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="head"></div>
```

Comment: помогло,только теперь не на всю страницу, вот html код, может что тут не так?( 
<div class="row">
       <div class= "col-md-12">
         <div class="head"> </div>
          <div class="container">
          
        <!---   <img class="head" src="img/head.jpg" alt="">--->
       </div>
       </div>
   </div>

Comment: @A.G картинкой можно или заполнилось полностью блок или же полностью ее в этом блоке разместить без ее потери. Заполнить ее полную и не обрезав ее, если блок не имеет пропорциональных размеров, физически нельзя изменить.

Comment: ничего не понял

Comment: теперь когда меньше делаю фон стает маленьким а текс норм,и между ними пространство огромное